# Build issues with Red Hat Linux and C++

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, g++, rhel

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux with bash shell.

I have a Makefile that references a directory using a variable, like this:

```
DIRVAR = ..
```

And then there is an include statement after, like the following:

`include ${DIRVAR}/dir1/dir2/rules.mk`

When I try to use this make file with "make" at the command line, I get this error:

> make: *** .: is a directory. Stop.

So then when I change the var to enclose it in quote marks, like the following:

`DIRVAR="."`

Then this error occurs when trying to do make:

> Makefile: /dir1/dir2/rules.mk no such file or directory

This project needs to use relative paths in the makefiles, hard coded paths will not work if someone tries to do a build with a different path than the hard coded path in the Makefile, Multiple developers working on the same project who may check out code to a different source folder.

Comment: There must be something subtlely different in your actual makefile than what you show here.  First, is that really the exact error message you get?  You don't get any kind of filename or linenumber?  If you do, are you sure that it points to the `include` line?  If it does, please check the `DIRVAR = ..` line and make sure that you don't accidentally have a space or something else, maybe even a non-printable character, in between the two `.` characters.

Comment: You should show the relevant code rather than trying to pull out the one line you think is the problem. For example, show the recipe, how make is being invoked, and the error. Just guessing, but `include ${DIRVAR}/dir1/dir2/rules.mk` should be changed to `include $(DIRVAR)/dir1/dir2/rules.mk`. `$(VAR)` is make syntax. See [How to Use Variables](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html) in the Make manual.

Comment: Actually, not able to display the actual code, it is protected by NDA, that is why I am using generic terms. Also this error did not seem to occur until after I used nano to edit it, was using nedit before that, could that be the reason?

Comment: @jww, both `$(var)` and `${var}` are valid syntax for accessing a `make` variable in POSIX-standard `make` in general and in GNU `make` (as shipped in RHEL) in particular.  Your linked document agrees.  The former is more traditional, and I prefer it, but using the latter is unlikely to be a problem in practice for the OP.

Comment: Ok I am not sure this is the reason, but these make errors started occurring after I used nano to edit the makefile, then when I edited the makefile using NEDIT (A gnome text editor app) then problems seemed to go away. NANO is the gnu equivalent of the Unix pico editor, much easier to use than VI. Also not sure about this either, but a MAKE CLEAN in the main application seemed to straighten out all the errors that were occurring.

Comment: I have free Unix and Linux shell accounts with tildeverse and SDF.ORG, the tildeverse IRC at http://irc.tilde.chat is a great Unix/Linux resource. Anyways from them I found out that makefile commands have to be preceded with tabs, not spaces. But GNU fixed this years ago with gmake, so it should not be a source of error on Linux. We are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) with Gnome at my job, our application is primarily in C++, but also some Java and Python. We use make to build the projects, and JENKINS also.

Comment: Anyways, I was getting strange errors while trying to MAKE a C application I was working with, the error seemed to be with using clang instead of gcc, the error would not occur on Linux, only the OpenBSD, it turns out the source of the error was using spaces in the makefile instead of tabs. And this error does not occur in Linux since the GNU fixed the issue years ago with gmake. go figure.